# How to solve that cannot find include file when compiling opencv3.0 with extra models with CMAKE 3.4.1 and VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmake, cross-compiling

When Building the OPENCV 3.0 with CMAKE 3.4.1 and VS2015. VS2015 presents the following mistakes:

```
error   C2264   “std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth>::tuple”: error；opencv_perf_core E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\core\perf\opencl\perf_channels.cpp   187 
error       Cannot open scr file "opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp"  opencv_xphoto   e:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\xphoto\src\grayworld_white_balance.cpp   43  
error   C1083   Cannot open include file: “opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp”: No such file or directory  opencv_xphoto   E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\xphoto\src\grayworld_white_balance.cpp   43  
error   C2610   “std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth>::tuple(const std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth> &)”:  E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\core\perf\opencl\perf_channels.cpp)    opencv_perf_core    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\tuple    328 
error   C2610   “std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth>::tuple(std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth> &&)”:  E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\core\perf\opencl\perf_channels.cpp) opencv_perf_core    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\tuple    329 
error   C2535   “std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth> &std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth>::operator =(const std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth> &)”:  E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\core\perf\opencl\perf_channels.cpp)   opencv_perf_core    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\tuple    463 
error   C2382   “std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth>::operator =”: E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\core\perf\opencl\perf_channels.cpp)    opencv_perf_core    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\tuple    463 
error   C2264   “std::tuple<cv::Size,perf::`anonymous-namespace'::MatDepth>::tuple”: 函数定义或声明中有error；未调用函数   opencv_perf_core    E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\core\perf\opencl\perf_channels.cpp   165 
error   C1083   Cannot open include file: “opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp”: No such file or directory  opencv_ximgproc E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\ximgproc\src\fgs_filter.cpp  38  
error   C1083   Cannot open include file: “opencv2/core/hal/hal.hpp”: No such file or directory opencv_aruco    E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\aruco\src\dictionary.cpp 44  
error   C1083   Cannot open include file: “opencv2/core/hal/hal.hpp”: No such file or directory opencv_ximgproc E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\ximgproc\src\sparse_match_interpolators.cpp  41  
error   C1083   Cannot open include file: “opencv2/core/hal/hal.hpp”: No such file or directory opencv_xfeatures2d  E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\xfeatures2d\src\sift.cpp 108 
error   C1083   Cannot open include file: “opencv2/core/hal/hal.hpp”: No such file or directory opencv_optflow  E:\OpenCV3\sources\modules\optflow\src\motempl.cpp  44  
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_aruco300d.lib”  opencv_test_aruco   E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\aruco\LINK 1   
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_optflow300d.lib”    opencv_test_optflow E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\optflow\LINK   1   
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_xfeatures2d300d.lib”    opencv_stitching    E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\stitching\LINK 1   
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_stitching300d.lib”  opencv_perf_stitching   E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\stitching\LINK 1   
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_xphoto300d.lib” opencv_perf_xphoto  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\xphoto\LINK    1   
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_ximgproc300d.lib”   opencv_perf_ximgproc    E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\ximgproc\LINK  1   
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_xfeatures2d300d.lib”    opencv_perf_xfeatures2d E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\xfeatures2d\LINK   1   
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_stitching300d.lib”  opencv_test_stitching   E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\stitching\LINK 1   
error   C2065   “vector_Rect2d”: Undeclared identifier  opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22172   
error   C2146   syntax error: missing“;”(在标识符“boundingBox”的前面)  opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22172   
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22172   
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22179   
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22181   
error   C2065   “vector_Rect2d”: Undeclared identifier  opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22191   
error   C2146   syntax error: missing“;”    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22191   
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22191   
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22197   
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22199   
error   C2065   “vector_Rect2d”: Undeclared identifier  opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22216   
error   C2146   syntax error: missing“;”opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22216   
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22216   
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22223   
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_types.h 22224   
error   C2065   “vector_Rect2d”: Undeclared identifier  opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_funcs.h 7839    
error   C2146   syntax error: missing“;”    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_funcs.h 7839    
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_funcs.h 7839    
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_funcs.h 7846    
error   C2065   “boundingBox”: Undeclared identifier    opencv_python2  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\python2\pyopencv_generated_funcs.h 7848    
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_xfeatures2d300d.lib”    opencv_test_xfeatures2d E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\xfeatures2d\LINK   1   
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_ximgproc300d.lib”   opencv_test_ximgproc    E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\ximgproc\LINK  1   
error   LNK1104 Cannot open file“..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_xphoto300d.lib” opencv_test_xphoto  E:\OpenCV3\sources\build\modules\xphoto\LINK    1
```

I thought the problem may come from "opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp" and “opencv2/core/hal/hal.hpp”. However after I specify the include file. more problem inside the code come up like such as there is no such thing like cv::hal etc. So I completely loss in the errors.

I use the following tutorial to config and compile my Cmake and VS: https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/

I need to use Xfeatures2d so what can I do to make it? Thank you very much and merry christmas~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your build with the OpenCV 3.1 source.

Since you are building Xfeatures2d it appears that you have added the opencv_contrib module to your source tree.  I did the same thing in the past week and the version of opencv_contrib that I downloaded would only build with OpenCV 3.1 which is now available.  With OpenCV 3.0 I had exactly the same first error message you are seeing (Cannot open scr file "opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp").  It appears that hal has been moved to core in OpenCV 3.1.

Give that a try. All modules are now building successfully for me under Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2012.  Note: 'opencv_extra_modules_path' must be set in CMake and I assume you also want 'with_cuda' set (and you have probably already checked that).  I am using CMake 2.8.12.2.