# Building OpenCV 3.1.0 from source with SIFT and SURF

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, opencv3.1

I'm trying to build OpenCV 3.1.0 (with the extra contrib packages) from source.

I'm following the instructions in [this tutorial](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/opencv-3-0-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-cmake-and-c/) to build it under Visual Studio 2015 and the ones in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657774/surf-and-sift-algorithms-doesnt-work-in-opencv-3-0-java) to re-enable the SIFT and SURF features, now under opencv_contrib.

All goes well except that the file `features2d_manual.hpp`, changed in [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657774/surf-and-sift-algorithms-doesnt-work-in-opencv-3-0-java), fails to compile with the following error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I am at a loss of what might be going on here, due to my poor understanding of how CMake and Visual Studio interact. The opencv_contrib modules are being properly added through the CMake variable `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH`.

Are any of you able to help? Thank you for your time reading this!

AP

Comment: So can you find the file `xfeatures2d.hpp` in your opencv source code?

Comment: Hello, yes, the sources are there, I can see the module being configured by CMake and I can also see it in the Visual Studio source tree.

Comment: Hi, according to the [**similar question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462222/how-to-solve-that-cannot-find-include-file-when-compiling-opencv3-0-with-extra-m) in stackoverflow,  please check you downloaded the [**stable 3.1 version of opencv_contrib**](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/3.1.0). You need to select the tag of 3.1, not just download the latest file I guess.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I am using the stable 3.1 sources, including the 3.1 contrib modules. And I am following the instructions in the page linked by the similar question you refer to.